# Numpy Array (What does that answer mean?)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Evaluate the results of the following statements for the following NumPy array A:

```
A = numpy.array([[8,3,1,0] , [2,2,4,-1] , [3,-2,1,6]])

>> z = A[[0,2],[3,0]] 
"Question: What is the output?"

array([0, 3]) "Answer"

>> t = numpy.where(A[1:3,1:]>2)
"Question: What is the output?"

(array([0, 1], dtype=int64), array([1, 2], dtype=int64)) "Answer"
```

I didn't understand the answer. What did we process the array?

Comment: Basic slicing.  Try, `A[[0, 2], :]`, then `A[:, [3, 0]]`, and finally `A[[0,2],[3,0]]`. You are selecting the rows 0 and 2 together with columns 3 and 0 (in that order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get elements from first (`[8,3,1,0]`) and third (`[3,-2,1,6]`) arrays of `A` (due to zero-based `[0,2]` specifications).

Now, from the first array you get element 3, i.e. fourth number which is `0`.

From the third array you get element 0, i.e. the first number which is `3`

For your second question you slice elements starting second from arrays starting second up to fourth, i.e. `[2,4,-1] , [-2,1,6]`

From those arrays you attempt to get elements more than 2. There are only two numbers - from array 0 and 1 and the corresponding elements (`4` and `6`) have order numbers 1 and 2 in python zero-based definition. This is the answer.

Comment: >> t = numpy.where(A[1:3,1:]>2)

Comment: Can you explain this :D What is the output? (array([0, 1], dtype=int64), array([1, 2], dtype=int64)) "Answer"

Answer (score 1):

It is called slicing. 
First get the value of A[[0,2]] where 0 is first item (list) and 2 is third item

```
array([[ 8,  3,  1,  0],
       [ 3, -2,  1,  6]])
```

Then A[[0,2],[3,0]] means get the third of first list and first item of second list. Thus,

```
array([0, 3])
```